# EF Core 2.0 Migrations With Context In Satellite Assembly and User Secrets

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have an API project that is a normal start up ASP.NET Core 2.0 application.

This solution also has a satellite assembly that contains our DbContext.

Opening a command prompt in the satellite assembly directory and attempting to run a CLI command like:

`dotnet ef migrations add UserAccountFields`

This results in:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A
>   provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring
>   method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider.

Which makes sense since there isn't any valid configuration for it to read.  It seems that the CLI doesn't allow specifying the provider or connection string in the command itself.  But you can when scaffolding a context from an existing database but we're using code first so that's not possible.

If I switch to the directory of the root application project and try:

`dotnet ef migrations add UserAccountFields -c ErsSecurityContext`

I get the error:

> No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Which also makes sense since the root application doesn't include references to the EF NuGets, and we don't want it to.

Our connection strings are also stored in UserSecrets which further complicates the situation.

**How can I make this scenario work without resulting in scattering connection strings in code by overriding the OnConfiguring method?**

I'm stumped. Our architecture is good but this is a complete show-stopper and I don't know how to go about using any of the nice CLI stuff to scaffold migrations.

Comment: See https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10806.

Comment: Excellent, this led me to my solution.  Will add an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after reading through the link Mark G provided.

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10806

I can now create migrations using this simple change to the command.  Navigate to the directory containing the project with your context and migrations, open a command prompt here and use:

```
dotnet ef migrations add <migration-name> -c <context-name> --startup-project <relative-path-to-startup-csproj-file>
```

This also works for other commands, such as:

```
dotnet ef database update --startup-project <relative-path-to-startup-csproj-file>

dotnet ef migrations remove --startup-project <relative-path-to-startup-csproj-file>
```